# Функция ready теперь не нужна?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Начиная с версии **3.0** как указано в документации `jQuery`, функцию `ready` теперь не нужно использовать,
хотел как раз по этому поводу спросить, правда ли можно заменить `ready` на `$()` ?

Пример:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  console.log('DOM загружен с помощью ready!'); 
});

$(function () {
  console.log('DOM загружен с помощью $()!');
});
```

А также можно ли вызывать прямо функцию с помощью данного метода?

Пример:

```
function hi(text) {  
  console.log(text);  
}  
$(hi('123'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть [исходники](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.7.1/src/core/init.js#L111) в них явно указано, что в случае если передается функция: `$(fn)` - будет вызвана функция `ready` с переданным параметром. Такое поведение было еще во второй версии.

Поэтому разницы вызывать `.ready(fn)` или `$(fn)` - нет.

---

> А также можно ли вызывать прямо функцию с помощью данного метода?

Нет, нельзя, так как аргументы переданные в функцию вычисляются до запуска функции и следующая запись

```
$(hi('123'));
```

эквивалентна

```
var hiResult = hi('123');
$(hiResult);
```

Comment: `function hi(text) {console.log(text); }  $(hi('123'));` Не совсем понял почему нельзя, если я из консоли спокойно запустил

Comment: @RSK, нельзя, потому что функция вызывается НЕ с помощью метода `$(...)` - она просто вызывается  и результат передается в качестве аргумента. Если убрать `$` ничего не поменяется в этом случае.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо за пояснение

Comment: Да, то есть в параметры выполнения код идёт не функциу, а просто в результат этой функции, и 
с начало выполнится hi('123') и уже в $() вместо функции уйдёт пустая строка, которая ничего не вызовет